# How do I find the first numerically sorted integer NOT in this list?

Tags: sql, database, sorting, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to go through a list of numbers and find the first number missing when the list is sorted numerically.

For example, consider this resultant set of numbers from a query:

```
A
---
0
1
3
4
5
```

I need a query to go through this list in numerical order from lowest to highest and return the first number missing from the list of numbers that would otherwise be complete and numerically sorted. So in the above example, the query should return ***2***. Below are some more examples. Requirements: must start checking at value 0, must return the first value missing from the NUMERICALLY SORTED list, must only return 1 number.

```
A
---
1
3
4
5

/* return 0 */

A
---
0
1
2
3
4
5
8
9

/* return 6*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query finds the first absent row in a sequence but fails to find numbers between zero and sequence start:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(T1.a + 1) 
  FROM A as T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  A as T2 ON T1.a + 1  = T2.a 
  WHERE T1.a > -1 AND T2.a IS NULL;
```

Basic idea - find all pairs row + previous row and use incomplete pairs to derive what value is missing.

Illustration:

```
CREATE TABLE A (a int);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (0) ;
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1) ;
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2) ;
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3) ;
--INSERT INTO A VALUES (4) ;
INSERT INTO A VALUES (5) ;
INSERT INTO A VALUES (6) ;
INSERT INTO A VALUES (7) ;

SELECT 
  T1.a, T2.a FROM A as T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  A as T2 ON T1.a + 1  = T2.a;
```

Output:

```
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   (null)
5   6
6   7
7   (null)
```

This solution [is slower](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) than NOT EXISTS on MS SQL. I find this fact fascinating, joins should be much easier to optimize.

Comment: First statement is about failure to capture missing 0

Comment: So then you do not know of a solution that works for a missing 0?

Comment: So then you do not know of a solution that works for a missing 0?

Comment: I could not find one qucikly,  no.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select top 1 a + 1
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.a + 1)
order by a;
```

Comment: Would not outer join be more effective?

Comment: This works, but I don't quite understand it. What is the WHERE clause doing? It seems to me that it is joining the table on itself and excluding the first row of `t2` and the last row of `t` from joining. Then, it selects a constant 1x the number of rows returned. But then it wants to find where this subquery returns no rows, which is where I get confused.

Comment: Fails second test (missing 0)

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
declare @upperBound int
select @upperBound = max(x) from yourTable    

;with a as (
select 0 x
union ALL
SELECT x + 1
from a
where a < @upperBound
)

select min(a.x)
from yourTable yt
 right join a
  on yt.x = a.x
where yt.x is null
```

Comment: I cannot specify the upper bound to the list of integers.

Comment: @DarthVoid you mean use a number other than 99?

Comment: Right. If I understand your answer correctly, you picked an arbitrary high value to check against. I cannot assume an upper bound in my situation.

Comment: Change 99 to (SELECT MAX(a) FROM yourtable) (or parameterise it). Probably going to be slow on larger result sets though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a numbers table, also called a tally table. You could create one on the fly as you need it, but that is really inefficient and the uses are common enough that I tend to have one already built on each server, fully indexed. There are plenty of articles about them - here's a quick example [Number tables explained part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/)

Assume you have built a TALLY table and the column is also called TALLY, your table is DATA and the column to check is ID

Find the highest number we need to check. (@Upperbound)
Then select every valid row from the tally table, left outer join your data table, and only keep the rows that do not have a match.  The lowest Tally left is the number you want

```
DECLARE @UpperBound int = (select MAX(ID) from DATA) 

SELECT TOP 1 T.TALLY
FROM TALLY T
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATA D on D.ID = T.TALLY
WHERE T.TALLY >= 0  --Lowest number to check
AND T.TALLY < @UpperBound  --got to be smaller than this
AND D.ID IS NULL  --only want rows that don't match
ORDER BY T.TALLY ASC
```